# How can I center a drawn object in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, centering

I am making a program that draws a circle on a `JFrame`. I want to start the program with the circle in the center of the screen so that even if the size of the `JFrame` window is changed, it is still centered. How would I do it? I have tried different things but haven't found anything that works yet. The code is down below:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int width = 40;
    int height = 40;
    int x = 160;
    int y = 70;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            }
    };

    public ImageFrame() {
        add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple math problem. Divide the difference of the container width and the circle `width` by 2 to locate the x co-ordinate for `drawOval`. Do the same for the `height` for the y co-ordinate.

Comment: How do I get the container width and height? Sorry if this is super simple.

Comment: ...as found in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)...

Comment: One last thing though. Should the circle still be centered even if I make the JFrame full screen?

Comment: this will be revealed when you try it ;)